# logs in Google App Engine Developement server using Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging

I am using Google App Engine with Java. I just want to view the logs in the console or a file.

I did the code like this.

```
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Constants.class.getName());
    log.log(Level.WARNING, "Test Log");
```

But is not displaying anywhere. I checked the local admin console for AppEngine, but it is not there also. Other posts says it will be displayed, but it is not displaying or not giving any errors. My Application works fine.

PS: This question have been asked a lot of places in internet, but none of them resolved my issue. That's why I am asking it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything started working when I used 32bit eclipse with 32bit JDK.

Answer (score 0):

In your appengine.web.xml, have you defined logging properties ?

```
<system-properties>
     <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="web-inf/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>
```

Secondly, appengine has different versions. Are you deploying on the same version for which you are looking for logs ?

Comment: I have the entry in appengine.web.xml. Also I use same version for deploying also. But I am trying to view logs in local development server, not on the could server.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below format and able to see warning message at local.

import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class ContactsAPI
{
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ContactsAPI.class.getName());

public Contact createContact(Contact contact)
    {
    log.warning("Input received data = " + contact);
}
}

Console log :

Jan 06, 2016 4:15:57 PM com.ContactsAPI createContact
WARNING: Input received data = id: null  [SYSTEM last_name ss] ]

Please check logging.properties should exist at "web-inf/logging.properties". I am attaching the logging properties file screen shot : http://snag.gy/HsB5q.jpg

Try to debug the code at log.warning(""); can help you if new line is coming in console or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Everything started working when I used 32bit eclipse with 32bit JDK..